# How does this C program to reverse a string using pointers work?

Tags: c

would you please explain to me step by step the algorithm of this C program to reverse a string using pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char str[50];
    char rev[50];
    char *sptr = str;
    char *rptr = rev;

    int i=-1;
    printf("Enter any string : ");
    scanf("%s",str);

    while(*sptr)
    {
        sptr++;
        i++;
    }

    while(i>=0)
    {
        sptr--;
        *rptr = *sptr;
        rptr++;
        --i;
    }


    *rptr='\0';
    printf("Reverse of string is : %s",rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a debugger to step through it whilst keeping a close watch on all variables.

Comment: It doesn't work. For instance, `while(i=0)` will not loop at all.

Comment: For me it is work quite well (compiled with gcc)

Comment: It reverses the string by traversing it from its end to its beginning, copying one character each time. But you should have searched first. SO is **full of** identical questions.

Comment: @unwind If user doesn't write string more than 50 symbols length than it works ok

Comment: Seriously, this is a reasonable question for a beginner. I'm not sure they would know what a similar question looks like. Lighten up people.

Comment: @DougT. I suggest you read P0W's comment above...

Comment: @H2CO3 are you assuming he somehow knows the OP? He sounds like he's just being sarcastic.

Comment: @DougT. And it sounds quite reasonable, honestly. Okay, let's say this is a "legitimate question" the first time it's asked. (I could argue against that, but anyway.) But given that there are literally dozens of duplicates of this question, the only thing that's safe to assume is that OP hasn't done absolutely any research before posting this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic is in this loop:

```
while(i>=0) // while there are more letters... (i was previously set to the number of letters)
{
    sptr--;  // decrement source pointer (points to end of source string
    *rptr = *sptr; // copy char
    rptr++; // increment target pointer
    --i; // decrement number of chars remaining
}
```

Rather straight forward, actually.

Comment: Wow. That escalated quickly. 3 upvotes under 6 seconds. I don't see why this answer would be so much better than the others.

Comment: Honestly, neither do I...

Comment: Simply put, inline explanation.

Comment: @StoryTeller `static inline`, mouhahaha...

Answer (score 2):

This cycle

```
while(*sptr)
{
    sptr++;
    i++;
}
```

Iterates over the string by incrementing `sptr` until it reaches the zero terminating character of the string. After the cycle `i` will correspond to the length of the string. Then in this cycle:

```
while(i>=0)
{
    sptr--;
    *rptr = *sptr;
    rptr++;
    --i;
}
```

`i` times we copy the character before the one pointed to by `sptr` in `rptr` and then we decrement sptr making it point to the previous character.

Answer (score 1):

This while loop calculates the size. `while` terminates when the expression evaluates to 0. C strings are terminated by null terminals, which when cast to an integer are 0s. So this loop keeps going until it detects the end of a C string as indicated by the presence of the null terminator which == 0. sptr and i move down the string, i counting the number of characters, sptr being incremented to point to the next character. Eventually `sptr` points to the end of the input string.

```
 while(*sptr)
 {
     sptr++;
     i++;
 }
```

In the next loop, while we still have characters left (remember i before this loop is the size of the string) we move our `sptr` backwards down the string (the last loop pointed it at the end of the string). Meanwhile another `rptr` is moving forwards through another string. The statement `*rptr = *sptr` copies from the backwards moving `sptr` to the fwd moving `*rptr` thus reversing the string.

```
while(i>=0)
{
    sptr--;
    *rptr = *sptr;
    rptr++;
    --i;
}
```